# How to setup Facebook App Domains localhost with port number (IIS Express)

Tags: c#, facebook, iis-7

I am try to implement some small login to my system with facebook,
my local solution is working under IIS Express and start via `http://localhost:7883/` but Facebook does't allow to write any localhost and port number at App Domains section.

> App Domains: `http://localhost:7883/` should not contain protocol
>   information.

how I can fix it ? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looks like no option, just need to use address with out port.